# What's the issue with the AVG function I'm using?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I keep getting an error on BigQuery SQL that says "No matching signature for aggregate function AVG for argument types: STRING. Supported signatures: AVG(INT64);"

This is my code:

```
SELECT 
march2021_data.ride_length AS ride_timeMARCH,
SAFE_CAST(march2021_data.ride_length AS INT64),
AVG(march2021_data.ride_length),
march2021_data.member_casual AS march_member_type


FROM 
cyclistic_2021_total_data.march2021_data

WHERE 
march2021_data.member_casual = 'casual'
```

Could somebody please explain why I'm not able to average the ride length for March?

Comment: error message is quite clear! what is the question really?

Comment: the error message is telling you that the AVG function accepts an 8byte integer value, but you gave it a string; check the type of march2021_data.ride_length in the table

Comment: So how can I change the value of my ride_length from a string to an integer? I thought that I had cast it to be in INT64 form, but I guess nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your `SAFE_CAST` inside the `AVG` function.  Also, because you are using an aggregate function with field projections, you need to supply a `GROUP BY` clause for all the non-aggregated fields.

```
SELECT 
  march2021_data.member_casual AS march_member_type, 
  AVG(SAFE_CAST(march2021_data.ride_length AS INT64))
FROM 
  cyclistic_2021_total_data.march2021_data
WHERE 
  march2021_data.member_casual = 'casual'
GROUP BY
  march2021_data.member_casual
```

You can simplify the query even more because there is only one member_casual group being returned as a result of the filter.  As such, you do not need the `GROUP BY` clause as the group is implied by the filter.

```
SELECT 
  AVG(SAFE_CAST(march2021_data.ride_length AS INT64))
FROM 
  cyclistic_2021_total_data.march2021_data
WHERE 
  march2021_data.member_casual = 'casual'
```

Comment: Awesome, the code was able to work but unfortunately it returns a null value for the average I'm looking for. I tried switching from SAFE_CAST to just CAST, but then I get an error message that tells me there's "bad int values," so it doesn't actually process. Is there a way to fix my data so that I don't have this issue?